# Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to AccountDAO

Tags: java, spring

Hello im doing a simple spring application and for some reason this error came up:

- Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to AccountDAO

I have 3 classes, AccountDao:

```
package com.luv2code.aopdemo.dao;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;

@Component
public class AccountDAO {

    public void addAccount() {

        System.out.println(getClass() + ": DOING MY DB WORK: ADDING AN ACCOUNT");

    }

}
```

DemoConfig:

```
package com.luv2code.aopdemo;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

@Configuration
@EnableAspectJAutoProxy
@ComponentScan("com.luv2code.aopdemo")
public class DemoConfig {



}
```

And MainDemoApp:

```
package com.luv2code.aopdemo;


import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

import com.luv2code.aopdemo.dao.AccountDAO;



public class MainDemoApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        //read spring config java class
        AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DemoConfig.class);

        //get the bean from spring container
        AccountDAO theAccountDAO = context.getBean("accountDAO", AccountDAO.class); //THE PROBLE IS HERE

        //call the business method
        theAccountDAO.addAccount();

        //close the context
        context.close();

    }

}
```

The error is in the MainDemoApp at AccountDAO theAccountDAO = context.getBean("accountDAO", AccountDAO.class);
(only the part after = is red)

Comment: can you show the error with stack trace ?

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 Type mismatch: cannot convert from Object to AccountDAO

 at com.luv2code.aopdemo.MainDemoApp.main(MainDemoApp.java:18)

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this:

`AccountDAO theAccountDAO = (AccountDAO) context.getBean("accountDAO", AccountDAO.class);`

Comment: i tried and got this:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchFieldError: INSTANCE
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.<init>(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:53)
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.<init>(AnnotatedBeanDefinitionReader.java:71)
 at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:66)
  and some more stuff i cant post cuz of character limit

Answer (score 0):

Try `context.refresh()` before `context.getBean(...)`call, if it does not help do following:

1. Annotate `MainDemoApp.java` with `@SpringBootApplication`.
2. Remove `@ComponentScan` from `DemoConfig` and create the `@Bean` explicitly.
3. Start in debug mode and see if hits bean creation for `AccountDAO`.

Answer (score 0):

I kept trying to remove (and readd if nothing changed) one library from buildpath, one by one, just to try even if i dont know what effect would have. After removing org.springframework.context.jar the error disappeared.

just lol. anyone could explain please?

Comment: That usually happens when your IDE does not have up to date information about the dependencies. In such scenarios `refresh dependencies` helps.